# Convert XLSM to XLSX in Power Automate

Tags: excel, xlsx, power-automate, smartsheet-api, xlsm

I have an XLSM file that is updated via a Power Automate flow daily. I want to use this file in Smartsheet's Data Shuttle to upload the data to Smartsheet, but Data Shuttle won't recognize the XLSM format.

Currently, I can manually save the file as an XLSX, but right now I need to do that every day. If possible, I want to create a Power Automate flow that saves a copy of the XLSM file as XLSX. I've looked through the current offerings for flow steps, and none seem to be able to do this for me

I don't care if the macros break -- they mostly serve as a tool for other people to better manipulate another worksheet on the file. I just want to make the file XLSX format so I can upload to Smartsheet with Data Shuttle, and I want this file to be overriden with an updated copy every time the flow updating the XLSM file runs.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you show us what you’ve tried thus far and where it’s not working for you?

Comment: I'm just not finding a single action in power automate that let's me convert an XLSM to XLSX, on Power Automate or online

Answer (score 0):

In desktop Excel, you do this using the Save command. In Power Automate Desktop, you also do this using the Save action.

Similarly, you cannot do this in Excel for web, and you cannot do this in Power Automate cloud flows.

[image]

Comment: Dang, was hoping to find a way to add it as a step to an automated cloud flow. So to confirm, there is no way to add a step to a Power Automate cloud flow that saves a copy of an XLSM file as an XLSX?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my issue. I added steps to download a copy of the data in CSV format, did the trick!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERlKV.png)